# Caching internals with a partially applied function

Tags: haskell, caching, closures, partial-application

Imagine such a function:

```
bar :: Foo -> A -> B -> C -> IO ()
```

That function performs some `IO` stuff using a `Foo` and other values. The `Foo` value has to be passed to `bar`, and can be retrieved from `IO` via this:

```
foo :: X -> IO Foo
```

Now, `A`, `B`, `C` and `X` are all plain pure values. I’d rather like such a `bar` function:

```
bar :: X -> A -> B -> C -> IO ()
```

And `Foo` would be generated in the `bar` function using the `X` value. If I do that :

```
let f = bar myX
```

`f :: A -> B -> C -> IO ()`. If I call that function several times, the `X` value remains the same because of partial application, but since it’s an `IO` effect, it will be generated each time. Is there a *native*, *built-in-ghc* way to perform some kind of caching so that the `Foo` value is generated once – for the generated closure? I guess it’s all boxing-related, but I never figured out how to do that without using dirty `IORef`, expanding the parameters of `bar`, which is ugly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are literally asking would break referential transparency, a big "no" in Haskell. So that leaves me with the question, should I show you the `unsafeLaunchMissiles` kind of method that does (sometimes, if you are lucky and optimizations don't break it) what you literally ask but is highly discouraged, or should I show the clean way that changes the types just a little? Let me try the latter.

If you make your `bar` have the following type instead:

```
bar :: X -> IO (A -> B -> C -> IO ())
```

Then you can use, in a `do` block:

```
f <- bar myX
```

Alternatively, if you think that misses the point of redefining `bar` to take an `X`, then instead keep your *first* type for `bar` and do

```
f <- bar =<< foo myX
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the `unsafeScheisse` functions, I don’t want that. Your solution makes me think of something I often use, like the function passed to `control`. I like it, it sounds promising.